# Ionic 2 is not working in local machine

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried to run the ionic 2 basic application from my ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS machine. After `ionic serve` command.

It's showing up to this message ,nothing is building after this message

```
> ionic-app-base@ ionic:serve /home/USER_NAME/Desktop/training/ionicProject/testProject
> ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"
```

following info based on ionic

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.2.2
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.10.1
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: can you add your package.json?

Comment: check `node_modules` folder present or not. If not then run `npm install` to install all the package module.

Comment: node_modules is there

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the app-scripts version in your package.json file. 
Make it to "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4" if not already. Try running npm install again inside your app folder. Run ionic serve again.

Comment: Also since you are on 16.04 do not forget to use "sudo"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I tried all versions of ionic/app-scripts 1.0.0 and above. the versions that work for me are 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 .

- **Try changing ionic/app-script version in package.json to 1.0.0 or 1.0.1**
- **Then run npm install in your app folder**
- **ionic serve (using sudo is not necessary.)**

-------ionic info-------

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: @codeExalibur in my packgage.json i am using ionic/app-scripts version 1.2.2. Do i need to change to any other version?

Comment: @Team ,  yes change it to 1.0.0 or 1.0.1